# ASP.NET Razor Pages Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, identity

I'm almost new to ASP.NET and I have a question about it.

I created a project - Web app with Razor Pages, I made dependency injection and also made some migrations. I have some classes like Student, Teacher, and Admin. I'm using Identity and code-first.

My problem is:
I have many users but for my DB it's only one table with all those users. I give them some roles, in one table I have UserId and RoleId, which means they have connections.

Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
[Id]                            NVARCHAR (450)     NOT NULL,
[UserName]                      NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
[NormalizedUserName]            NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
[Email]                         NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
[NormalizedEmail]               NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
[EmailConfirmed]                BIT                NOT NULL,
[PasswordHash]                  NVARCHAR (MAX)     NOT NULL,
[SecurityStamp]                 NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
[ConcurrencyStamp]              NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
[PhoneNumber]                   NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
[PhoneNumberConfirmed]          BIT                NOT NULL,
[TwoFactorEnabled]              BIT                NOT NULL,
[LockoutEnd]                    DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
[LockoutEnabled]                BIT                NOT NULL,
[AccessFailedCount]             INT                NOT NULL,
[AreaCodeAndTown]               NVARCHAR (100)     NULL,
[Discriminator]                 NVARCHAR (MAX)     DEFAULT (N'') NOT NULL,
[Name]                          NVARCHAR (50)      NULL,
[RoadNameAndNumber]             NVARCHAR (100)     NULL,
[StudentUser_Name]              NVARCHAR (50)      NULL,
[TeacherUser_AreaCodeAndTown]   NVARCHAR (100)     NULL,
[TeacherUser_Name]              NVARCHAR (50)      NULL,
[TeacherUser_RoadNameAndNumber] NVARCHAR (100)     NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

Student class:

```
public class StudentUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [NotMapped] //ignore
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare(nameof(Password))]
    [NotMapped] //ignore
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Teacher class:

```
public class TeacherUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string RoadNameAndNumber { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string AreaCodeAndTown { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [NotMapped] //ignore
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare(nameof(Password))]
    [NotMapped] //ignore
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<AdminUser> AdminUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentUser> StudentUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeacherUser> TeacherUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

Question:
How I can get exactly Teacher or Student from this table "Users"? I searched in google, but almost all information about MVC, not about Razor Pages.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First, I would expect most of what you find for MVC to be relevant to Razor Pages. But your table design has issues. You shouldn't put both teacher and student details in the user table.

Comment: What do I suppose to do then with them? Create new tables with Teacher and Student, but they are users, how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

I have to change my Discriminator, cause there was only IdentityUser, but I tried to call StudentUser or TeacherUser.

Now everything is perfect. I hope this info can help someone.